# Dynamic formula that subtracts 2 cell values based on values from 2 other cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am struggling coming up with a title for this question as I cant figure out how best to put it. I believe I will be able to explain my question better below with pictures.

This also may be too demanding for a formula and need VBA coding

I would like to generate a formula that analyzes a range of 2 columns of values. The first column is the adjusted closing price for a stock. The Second column is a calculated oscillator aimed at predicting over and underbought status.

In this formula, a stock is considered underbought if the calculated oscillator  is below 30 and overbought if it is above 80. Therefore I would like to calculate the closing price price difference between the first occurrence of underbought and the next instance of overbought.

I then want this formula to loop through all instances of the stock price for the year. In theory there will be multiple times when the stock is ounderbought and overbought.

I think of these ranges in periods essentially. The start of the period is the first instance of a underbought number following the last instance of a overbought value. The end of the period is the next overbought value.

The number of days the stock is underbought/overbought will range wildly and therefore this needs to be a dynamic formula.

Ive considered using nested if and choose statements, but I cant come up with something robust enough. Could someone point me in the right direction with what functions to use to accomplish this? Is this something that is going to require VBA?

Example of what I would like to do

[image]

Thank you for taking the time to read and think on this. Please let me know if I can clarify anything for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up a little finite state machine for this sort of problem and it doesn't matter if you use VBA or helper columns.

So there are three states

(1) Initial state

(2) 'Primed' state

(3) In period state

and three transitions

(A) From (1) to (2) when overbought stock found

(B) From (2) to (3) when next underbought stock found

(C) From (3) back to (1) when next overbought stock found.

So you need to set up a column to handle these states and transitions containing the formula

```
=IF(AND(I2=1,H3>80),2,IF(AND(I2=2,H3<30),3,IF(AND(I2=3,H3>80),1,I2)))
```

starting in (say) I3  (I2 is set to 1).

Then you need two more helper columns to count the period ends and starts

```
=IF(AND(I1=2,I2=3),MAX(J$1:J1)+1,"")

=IF(AND(I1=3,I2=1),MAX(K$1:K1)+1,"")
```

And finally a column to pick up the differences

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(G$2:G$100,MATCH(ROWS(L$1:L1),J$2:J$100,0))-INDEX(G$2:G$100,MATCH(ROWS(L$1:L1),K$2:K$100,0)),"")
```

[image]

The VBA to find the difference for the nth period would look as below - you would call it like this starting in (say) I2

```
=IFERROR(stock(G$2:G$100,H$2:H$100,ROWS(N$1:N1)),"")
```

so as you pull the formula down it will look for the next period.

```
Option Explicit

Function Stock(Actual As Range, Predicted As Range, n As Integer) As Variant

Dim i, rows, LastRow, period As Long
Dim state As Integer
Dim startFound, endFound As Boolean
Dim actualValue, predictedValue, startValue, endValue As Double

state = 1
period = 0
startFound = False
endFound = False
rows = Actual.rows.Count
If rows <> Predicted.rows.Count Then
    Stock = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    Return
End If

For i = 1 To rows
    actualValue = Actual.Cells(i, 1).Value
    predictedValue = Predicted.Cells(i, 1).Value

    If state = 1 And predictedValue > 80 Then
        state = 2
    Else
        If state = 2 And predictedValue < 30 Then
            state = 3
            period = period + 1
            If period = n Then
                startValue = actualValue
                startFound = True
            End If
        Else
            If state = 3 And predictedValue > 80 Then
                state = 1
                If period = n Then
                    endValue = actualValue
                    endFound = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

Next I

If startFound And endFound Then
    Stock = startValue - endValue
Else
    Stock = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I think I miss stated my goal initially. I would like for the states to be successive. What I mean is that State 1 would be the first instance of underbought status to the first instance of overbought status. State 2 would be the next first instance of underbought status to the next first instance of overbought status. This pattern carried on through the worksheet till nothing is left. I assume there will be between 7-15 states total. So instead of having only 3 states and the formula calculating between these 3, is it possible to have it assign unique

Comment: numbers to each state? Again, thanks so much for taking the time to work on this!

Comment: It's a wet day here and not too much else happening to be honest so a good chance to practise my VBA. The thing is the states do cycle round from 1 to 2 to 3 and back to 1, but each time the period number goes up by one so it should be able to handle any number of periods (only two in the actual data). Where it might need tweaking is that the state is set back to 1 at the end of the period, maybe that should be 2 because the period ends on an overbought stock so the next underbought one should probably trigger a new period.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Could you clarify what to change in the formula? I have played around with the formula and cant get the periods to assign right. I still cant get it to number in a increasing order. It only numbers from 1-3. If I increase the reset value it still repeats the numbers just at a higher level.

Comment: I've got it set on my home PC so won't be able to go through the formulae until this evening. I didn't give an example of how to call the UDF - will add it to my answer.

Comment: Have put in a screenshot with some data to show it counting up to six periods using either VBA or helper columns.

Comment: Thanks so much for putting the picture up! Could you also put up the code that you changed to get it to generate  6 periods instead of repeating the values of 1-3?

Comment: @Josiah I haven't changed the code at all, just mocked up some new data so that there are 6 periods.

Comment: The period generation didn't quite work, but I was able to cannibalize someone else's code to make that part work. Your difference formula worked excellently. Thank you!